# An exception throw has type `Nothing`?

Tags: scala, exception, throw

As stated here - [Chapter 7 of Programming in Scala, Built-in Control Structures, 7.4 Exception handling with try expressions](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html):

> *In Scala, throw is an expression that has a result type.*
>
> *Technically, an exception throw has type `Nothing`. You can use a throw as an expression even though it will never actually evaluate to anything. This little bit of technical gymnastics might sound weird, but is frequently useful in cases like the previous example. One branch of an if computes a value, while the other throws an exception and computes `Nothing`. The type of the whole if expression is then the type of that branch which does compute something.*

The example is:

```
val half =
  if (n % 2 == 0)
    n / 2
  else
    throw new RuntimeException("n must be even")
```

Then I went to Scala and try:

```
scala> val n = 1
n: Int = 1

scala> val half = if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2 else throw new RuntimeException("n must be even")
java.lang.RuntimeException: n must be even
  ... 29 elided

scala> half
<console>:12: error: not found: value half
       half
       ^
```

It is saying that `half` is not found. However, based on the book, I assume it should say it is defined and it is with type `Nothing`.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is saying that half is not found. However, based on the book, I
>   assume it should say it is defined and it is with type Nothing.

If you re-read that paragraph, you'll see that the type of `half` shouldn't be `Nothing`, it should be `Int`:

> The type of the whole if expression is then **the type of that branch
>   which does compute something.**

The branch which does compute a value produces the type `Int`. You can prove this by defining `half` as a method and not a value:

```
scala> def half = if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2 else throw new RuntimeException("n must be even")
half: Int
```

If you actually want to see that `throw` has type `Nothing`, add it in your IDE and make it show the type:

```
val exception: Nothing = throw new RuntimeException("n must be even")
```

Regarding `half`, it isn't found because it's declaration throws an exception, which makes the REPL unable to bind a value to it.

Comment: My question is that, as it is stated in the book: *throw is an expression that has a result type*.  However, exception throw is not having any type to val.

Comment: @ChangLiu It does have a value, you're simply not able to see it since the value is never initialized (since it throws an exception on initialization). You can see that using a method definition (`def`) or a function, you can see that the return type is `Int`.

Comment: If it is never initialized, where does the statement *an exception throw has type `Nothing`* come from? Where the type `Nothing` is shown? In other word, is there any way to prove that type `Nothing`?